# advise around org-add-note behaves differnt in Windows and macOS

Tags: org-mode, advice

I have the following in my `init.el` file:

```
(defun my::with-no-drawer (func &rest args)
    (interactive "P")
    (let ((org-log-into-drawer (car args)))  
      (funcall-interactively func args)))

  (advice-add 'org-add-note :around #'my::with-no-drawer)
```

The idea is that if I do `M-x org-add-note` then `org-log-into-drawer` is `nil` and so the note is added in the main body of the TODO item, but if I do `C-u M-x org-add-note` then the note would be added to the LOGBOOK drawer.

This works fine in Linux and macOS systems, but has no effect in a Windows installation (the note is always placed in the drawer).

Any idea why? The `init.el` is identical across all systems.

Comment: Is the Emacs version older on the Windows computer?

Comment: The Emacs on the Windows computer is newer,  27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32.